# jdbc why prepared statement does not support named parameters?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, parameters

For example, query:

```
select * from Foo where brand=? and color=? and size=?
```

Why does Jdbc not support parameters in the following format

```
 :name, ?1, ?5
```

This would be much easier (and readable) to identify a parameter. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Because that syntax isn't part of SQL. The `:name` syntax is part of *embedded* SQL, but, sadly, JDBC isn't embedded SQL.